# How to fill NA values for a set of Primary key grouping in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My Input dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'col1': [20, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 25, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 20, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,25, np.nan,np.nan, np.nan],
    'col2': [np.nan, 'a',np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'b', np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 'c', np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 'd', np.nan, np.nan],
    'col3': [np.nan, np.nan, 'aa', np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,'bb', np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,'cc', np.nan,np.nan, np.nan,'dd', np.nan],
    'col4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 50, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 200,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 100,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 300]
})
```

**INPUT**:

[image]

I need to roll up the missing values for all the columns for the grouping of 'Key' & 'col1'. OR basically fill in the NAN values with the only available non-null value under that column in that grouping.

I am tried fillna with bfill & ffill methods, but it doesn't fill the values correctly as it picks the available value from the upper or lower grouping (specially the cells at the border of group)
The output should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with remove each column separately with [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and `Series` constructor:

```
f = lambda x : x.apply(lambda y: pd.Series(y.dropna().to_numpy()))
df1 = (df.groupby('key').apply(f)
         .drop('key', 1)
         .dropna(how='all')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   key  col1 col2 col3   col4
0    1  20.0    a   aa   50.0
1    1  25.0    b   bb  200.0
2    2  20.0    c   cc  100.0
3    2  25.0    d   dd  300.0
```

Or use reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape back by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('key').stack().to_frame('val')
df1 = (df1.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)['val']
         .unstack(1)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   key col1 col2 col3 col4
0    1   20    a   aa   50
1    1   25    b   bb  200
2    2   20    c   cc  100
3    2   25    d   dd  300
```

Or you can create lists first and then explode for `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('key').agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())
comp =[pd.DataFrame(df1[x].tolist(), index=df1.index) for x in df1.columns]
df1 = (pd.concat(comp, axis=1, keys=df1.columns).stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
   key  col1 col2 col3   col4
0    1  20.0    a   aa   50.0
1    1  25.0    b   bb  200.0
2    2  20.0    c   cc  100.0
3    2  25.0    d   dd  300.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this one out